# Find all $a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $3a+6$ divides $a^2+11$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Find all $a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $3a+6$ divides $a^2+11$

This problem has stumped me. I don't even know where to begin solving it. I know the solutions will be all $a$ such that
$$\frac{a^2+11}{3a+6}=k$$
with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

But I really don't know how to follow from here

Comment: Long division should help. $\frac{a^2+11}{a+2}=a + \frac{15}{a + 2} - 2$ so $(a+2)|15$ and we're left with $8$ possibilities, which can be done by hand.

Comment: Note that $9(a^2+11)=(3a)^2+99=(3a+6)(3a-6)+135$. Can you continue now?

Comment: By the way, there are solutions in negative integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $3a+6$ divides $a^2+11$, then $3a+6$ divides $3a^2+33$.

$3a+6$ also divides $3a^2+6a$, so this means $3a+6$ divides $6a-33$, or $a+2$ divides $2a-11$.

$a+2$ also divides $2a+4$, so this means $a+2$ divides $15$.

$15$ does not have many factors, so I leave you to check them.